# Raspberry pi blocks completely after multiple reboots

Tags: linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, reboot, rsyslog

I have a c++ program running on login on the raspberry pi, 
this program checks data for multiple devices attached on to it (Arduino Mega 2560 + Modbus RS485), gets inputted data from them and sends that to  mysql database.

The program itself runs fine, but after (what i suppose is causing the problem) rebooting several times the raspberry completely blocks after giving me some weird info (see pic)
(the program reboots the raspberry pi when it cant reach the mysql db or it cant connect to any of the devices)

I can't be sure of what the problem is since my program will easily run +12hourse before bloking the rPi so i can't really monitor my screen for errors or anything

[image: Error after failure]

Or a close - up

Download -> [Kern.log & syslog.log files](https://we.tl/uyDudTjnAv)

Comment: Did you look at the syslog entries that come before those dumps?

Comment: Where can i do that ?

Comment: By default it would be in `/var/log/syslog`.

Comment: I see the raspberry pi rebooted at 20:17 and then everything stops (no more log entries) the same goes for the kern.log and the mysql.log

Comment: ( and no errors in the rebooting process )

Comment: I mean to check earlier when the problem actually happened.

Comment: the problem occured @ 20:35 so this is earlier , and there aren't any errors :/ and since this is the closest to 20:35 there should be something that went wrong here and not 10minutes before , right ?

Comment: I agree that 10 minutes seems like a long time, but it would certainly have appeared before anyways.

Comment: Okay i will keep looking in the meantime i'm uploading the files in case i would miss something (not trying to make anyone do my work for me )